# Bootstrap Autocomplete (typeahead) does not work

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to make a autocomplete textbox that uses Bootstrap's typeahead functions. I have tested it through an array in javascript, manually typed. However I tried to add code that would allow autocomplete to use data from a mysql database, but I can't get this to work. What can I do to fix this so that autocomplete will show suggested words from a MySQL database?

HTML (test2.html)

```
<div class="well">  
    <input type="text" class="span3" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" />  
</div>  

<script>    
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'source.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: 'false',
            success: function(data){
                typeahead.process(data);
            }
        });
    } 
});     
</script>
```

PHP (source.php)

```
<?php 

include 'connect.php'; // connects to database

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $mysql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country WHERE country LIKE '%{$query}%'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_query)) {  
        $array[] = $row['name'];
    }

    json_cnode($array)

}
```

Comment: what is the error ... what are you getting ... what is the problem ... did you debug ?

Comment: json_cnode($array) .. not json_encode[$array]; ... that should be throwing an error there atleast

Comment: Still didn't work. The problem is that nothing happens when I type in (aka autosuggest doesn't activate) so I don't know the source of the problem. I know the mysql query works for sure though, so that's not the problem.

Comment: have you checked the error log ??

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: I know that http://www.jshint.com/ doesn't report a Javascript error while http://phpcodechecker.com/ doesn't report a PHP error

Comment: Haven’t you noticed the typo in @lagbox’s suggestion?

Comment: Yeah I know, I planned on securing the textbox once I figure out how to get it to work. But thanks for telling me.

Comment: did you check YOUR error log on YOUR SERVER ?

Comment: Yeah, it's json_encode($array) right? I added that in but no autosuggestion shows up

Comment: @user3377126  ..... DID YOU CHECK YOUR ERROR LOG ?

Comment: Sorry, a bit of a beginner at this. How would I check my error log if one uses Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the next part of your code:

`json_cnode ($array)`

It should say:

`echo  json_encode ($array);`